# Identify if userId contains digits at end of string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, count

I want to achieve this.

1. Total Number of unique users last week for non-transitioning users (The user ID pattern doesn't contain 3 digits at the end)
2. Total Number of unique users last week for transitioning users (The user ID pattern contains 3 digits at the end)

```
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
         (
            [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
            [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
            [userID] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
        (
            [ID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
    select 'Total Number of Transition Users' Name, convert(varchar(20), count(DISTINCT  userID)) 'Number'
    from.[dbo].Table1 where userID = (SELECT RIGHT(userID, 3))
    AND Date>= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
    UNION
    select 'Total Number of Non- Transition Users' Name, convert(varchar(20), count( DISTINCT userid)) 'Number'
    from [dbo].Table1 where userID <> (SELECT RIGHT(userID, 3))
    AND Date>= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `like` and a `case` expression to assign a type to each user, and then aggregate:

```
select x.usertype, count(distinct userid) cnt
from [dbo].table1 t
cross apply (values (
    case when t.userid like '%[0-9][0-9[0-9]' then 'transition' else 'non transition' end,
    t.userid
)) x(usertype, userid)
where t.date >= dateadd(day,-7, getdate())
group by x.usertype
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer. How your solution is checking last 3 digit in string. Thank you

Comment: @KeentoLearn: condition `t.userid like '%[0-9][0-9[0-9]'` checks if `userid` ends with 3 digits.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. what is benefit of using `cross apply`.

Comment: @KeentoLearn: we need the user type in both the `select` and `group by` clauses. Using `cross apply` avoids repeating the expression; it is computed just once, and then we can use it in both clauses.

Comment: Hi, one small help. how to order the sequence if `case when t.userid like '%[0-9][0-9[0-9]' then 'Total Number of Transition' else 'Total Number of non Transition' end,` Transition sequence should come first then followed by non transition. Currently, non transition is coming first then transition.

Comment: @KeentoLearn: just add an `order by` clause at the very end of the query. `order by usertype` should do it.